# jquery setInterval ie9 does not fire

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, setinterval

Like the title says.
Works on chrome and firefox, just IE9 gives me this issue.
It does work when I target frame directly (example.com/#target)
I dont think it's a matter of the object not being loaded

```
    setInterval("myFunc()",1);      

    function myFunc(){   
    if ($(shop).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#shpbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    } else if ($(about).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#abtbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    } else if ($(contact).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#cntbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    } else if ($(blog).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#extbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    } else if ($(collective).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#colbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    } else if ($(main).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('navopen').addClass('nav');
        $('#content').removeClass('contenthide').addClass('content');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen'); 
        $('#bgmain').addClass('bgopen');
    } else if ($(pmt).is(":target")) {
        $('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('navopen');
        $('#content').removeClass('content').addClass('contenthide');
        $('.bgopen').removeClass('bgopen');
        $('#abtbg').addClass('bgopen'); 
    }

    else {

    }}
```

I've tried wrapping it in window(load), document(ready) to no avail...

Comment: Am I missing something, [jquery selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) does not list `:target`?!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: As a side-note: `setInterval` is a global JavaScript method. Your question title implies it is a method of the jQuery library. Propably should be "window setInterval..." or just "setInterval...".

Comment: @Jamiec [`:target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo) is a CSS pseudo-class which will work in jQuery only if the browser supports it natively, which [IE9 does](http://caniuse.com/#search=:target)

Comment: no errors in console
i've tried just 'setinterval' to no avail

Comment: Are all the variables you use inside the jQuery selector calls in the if conditions defined and referring to DOM elements? Id est, are you sure you don't mean either `$('#bgmain').is(...)` or `main.is(...)`  instead of `$(main).is(...)` ?

Comment: which is confusing because it should of come up in the console

Answer (score 1):

You should really refactoring your code!

The setting of an interval with delay of 1 ms is useless in your case and can only cause bugs as minimum for browser to call an interval callback function is over than this 1 ms.

Change your logic code and try with this instead:

```
setInterval(myFunc,100);
```